# API Giving error while using POST activity with python , but working on POSTMAN

Tags: python, api, python-requests

In the code as per the documentation we have to make a API call where they have used Authorization Header of type Basic Auth(Username:Password) and Request header has values Content_Type and DealerName. We have to generate the token.

```
type here
`import requests
import base64

api_url = "url"
auth_username = "user1"
auth_password = "pass1"
request_headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'dealerName': 'c1'
}

auth_str = f'{auth_username}:{auth_password}'
auth_bytes = auth_str.encode('ascii')
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(auth_bytes)
base64_str = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
request_headers['Authorization'] = f'Basic {base64_str}'


 
response = requests.post(api_url, headers=request_headers, allow_redirects=True)


if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    response_data = response.json()
    print(response_data)
else:
    print('Error:', response.status_code, response.reason)`
```

I have tried the python code but it is giving me 405 method not allowed. Even though the POST method is working properly in POSTMAN

Comment: Are you sure POST is what you want? And Requests can handle basic auth for you: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: @ivvija yes POST is what i want. While I hope Requests should handle basic auth

Comment: Instead of making auth header manually, you can provide Basic Auth login and pass as keyword argument auth with a tuple: `requests.post(api_url, headers=request_headers, allow_redirects=True, auth=(auth_username, auth_password))` + instead of printing just `response.reason`, which is purely translation of status code, consider printing response.content to actually see what the server complains about - some apis are written with disregard to actual meanings of the status codes